# showCalendar is not defined

Tags: php, joomla, calendar, joomla3.0

In joomla 1.5 I used the following, to show the calendar.

```
<?php JHTML::_('behavior.calendar'); ?>

<input type="reset" class="button" value="..." onclick="return showCalendar('startdate','%Y-%m-%d');" />
```

How can i rich same in joomla 3.0 ? Now i get `Uncaught ReferenceError: showCalendar is not defined`

Thanks

Comment: you need to define showCalendar.... You probably need to include a script where it is defined.

Comment: All scripts are there, because i call `JHTML::_('behavior.calendar');`

Comment: checked the source of your page to see if it is really there?

Comment: Done already, they are in correct place! I think in joomla 3.0 they change the structure, but i can't find documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
<?php echo JHTML::_('calendar', $startdate, "mydate" , "mydate", '%Y-%m-%d');?>
```